# I cannot import python module

Tags: python, module, environment, python-module, modulenotfounderror

software files structure is as follow:

- ModelSchema   <<< I am right now here

  - DomainClasses

    - joint.py
  - Manage

    - manage_joint.py

now I want to import "joint" module in "manage_joint" so, I put the path of "DomainClasses" directory to the environment of "manage_joint.py" file:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r".\DomainClasses"))
```

then

```
from DomainClasses import joint
```

but there is error occurred: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DomainClasses'

what is wrong with me?

Comment: You should put `__init__.py` files in each of the directories and not use `sys.path.append`. That should get you part way, but it's not easy to understand your structure exactly. Unrelated side note; "what is wrong with me?" implies that you are asking about _yourself_, not your code and could be read in a way you don't want. "What is wrong with my code?"